# insert image with session

Tags: php, html

I store a pictures name in the database, and but it to a folder. 
Now I want to insert that picture like this:

```
<?php $image = "/uploads/" . $_SESSION['profile_picture'] ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image?>" width="100" height="100">
```

It says:

> Bad value "" for attribute "scr" on element "img":DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in PATH
>                       Syntax of IRI reference:
>                       Any URL. For example:'/hello/','#carvas', 'http://exaple.org'. Character should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

Comment: Echo `$image`, what does it return?

Comment: if you store into db, then why use Session variable?
Have you store value into session from Database?

Comment: I assume its because you are not setting the session variable right.. try setting $_SESSION['profile_picture'] = image.jpg right before it loads and make a file called that.

Comment: echo $inage returns this: /uploads/poster_rodents_big.jpg

Comment: can you pest exact your error

Comment: @Rayf value will not be set then Notice: Undefined index: profile_picture will be generate but he is saying Bad value..

Comment: @NanheKumar Thats exactly my point of setting a static value.. Since the bad value is generated by an empty variable.. So the session variable is not set correctly..

Comment: but the echo $inage returns correctly: /uploads/poster_rodents_big.jpg

Comment: Gives an error like this:
Bad value "" for attribute "scr" on element "img":DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in PATH
                    Syntax of IRI reference:
                    Any URL. For example:'/hello/','#carvas', 'http://exaple.org'. Character should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20

Comment: Why are not posting your exact error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took an extra character. The correct code is the following:

```
<?php $image = "uploads/" . $_SESSION['profile_picture'] ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image?>" width="100" height="100">
```